# predict is not giving the highest probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am using SVM from sklearn (Python 3). The predicted class probability is lesser than the highest probability among all classes. Can somebody explain this.

```
    clf = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer()), ('clf', svm.SVC())])
    parameters = {'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 2)], 'vect__stop_words': ['english'],
                  'vect__lowercase': [True], 'clf__C': [1,2, 5, 10, 20, 100],
                  'clf__kernel': [str('linear')], 'clf__class_weight':['balanced'],
                  'clf__probability': [True]}
    vec_clf = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring='f1_weighted')
    vec_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Print statements.

```
    pred_data = model.predict(input_series)
    probability_lst = model.predict_proba(input_series)[0]
    print ("probability lst: ", probability_lst)
    print ("predicted data: ", pred_data)
    print ("classes: ", model.best_estimator_.classes_)
```

This is the code I am using. Please find the below print output.

```
    probability lst:  [ 0.29004279  0.38866277  0.04441053  0.1173824   0.0300703   0.0983329   0.03109831]
    predicted data:  ['1']
    classes:  ['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7']
```

Logically it should predict class "2" as it has highest probability. Please explain this output

Comment: Why are you accessing `model.predict_proba(input_series)[0]`, emphasis on the `[0]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusing probabilities of the predict\_proba of scikit-learn's svm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674164/confusing-probabilities-of-the-predict-proba-of-scikit-learns-svm)

Comment: it was a list of list, so I took [0]

Comment: @VivekKumar  As mentioned in the other link shared by you, I tried decision function as well. but could not understand the output. Here is the output.

Comment: dec fun:  [[  4.24585270e-02   4.96189478e-01   2.49730266e-01   5.74115210e-01
    2.91674509e-01   5.43911786e-01   6.57224118e-01   2.65190816e-01
    7.28700141e-01   3.96157293e-01   1.10457723e+00  -2.27747710e-01
    1.64406656e-01  -2.79911772e-01   8.23904997e-02   3.42637709e-01
   -9.38947411e-05   3.42586750e-01  -4.11551164e-01  -8.49533033e-02
    3.48155592e-01]]

Comment: I have 7 classes, and this output is around 21. How can I get the class name with highest score

Comment: This is because SVC does not directly support multiclass classification, what you're seeing is a One vs One classification output. The class name with the "highest score" will be the one output by `predict`.

Answer (score 0):

I have read some docs on predict, I think it works in different way not synced with predict_proba.

So using predic_proba and taking the highest probability and its corresponding class(from model.classes_)

We can close this ticket.