# Predicting Class in Multiclass classification using SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

```
In:svc1.predict([X_poly[25].reshape(1,-1))

Out:array([3], dtype=int64)

In:svc1.decision_function([X_poly[25]])

Out:array([[ 0.58348329, -0.99979492,  0.08571431, -0.99996706, -0.52397444,
     0.99959056]])

In:svc1.predict_proba(X_poly[25].reshape(1,-1))

Out:array([[ 0.48373954,  0.11870606,  0.00261101,  0.39494339]])
```

I am using rbf kernel and 'ovo' classification. I am trying to predict the class of 26th sample in the data. The SVC classifier predicted the class sample as 3. However, I am not able to comprehend how does it narrow down to class 3 when probabilities suggest the other way. Can you also please advise the interpretation of the output of decision_function method and how it is used to predict the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scikit-learn predict\_proba gives wrong answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017882/scikit-learn-predict-proba-gives-wrong-answers)

Comment: Also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111408/how-does-sklearn-svm-svcs-function-predict-proba-work-internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) suggests:

> The probability model is created using cross validation, so the
>   results can be slightly different than those obtained by predict.
>   Also, it will produce meaningless results on very small datasets.

I think this is why you have different outputs.

As for the `ovo` (one-vs-one) decision function, since your decision function returns 6 values that means you have 4 classes:

`(n*(n-1))/2 = 6`, where n is the number of classes.

Now for how to predict the class using the numbers returned from the decision function. As the name suggests (one-vs-one), it compares the classes one-to-one and then outputs a positive or a negative number on which class it thinks is the right one. In your case, and since we have 4 classes, it produces 6 numbers which represent the comparison between your classes (1,2,3,4) as follows: `[12,13,14,23,24,34]` which is represented in your case by this decision vector:

```
[0.58348329, -0.99979492,  0.08571431, -0.99996706, -0.52397444, 0.99959056]
```

So, which class wins depends on the signal of the numbers, so in this example, the winner classes are: `[1,3,1,3,4,3]`, i.e. `'12'` is compared by `0.58348329`, hence class `'1'` wins ... etc. Therefore, the decision function votes the class `'3'` as your prediction since it is the most winning class.