# Predict probabilities using SVM

Tags: python, classification, svm, libsvm

I wrote this code and wanted to obtain probabilities of classification.

```
from sklearn import svm
X = [[0, 0], [10, 10],[20,30],[30,30],[40, 30], [80,60], [80,50]]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
clf = svm.SVC() 
clf.probability=True
clf.fit(X, y)
prob = clf.predict_proba([[10, 10]])
print prob
```

I obtained this output:

```
[[0.15376986 0.07691205 0.15388546 0.15389275 0.15386348 0.15383004 0.15384636]]
```

which is very weird because the probability should have been

```
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

(Observe that the sample for which class has to be predicted is same as 2nd sample) also, probability obtained for that class is the lowest.

Comment: probability should sum up to 1. It does not mean that they should be 0 or 1! You can use argmax to choose the highest probability. In your case, the probability of 6 classes is equal. Therefore, it can belong to any class but not class 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**: As pointed out by @TimH, the probablities can be given by `clf.decision_function(X)`. The below code is fixed. Noting the appointed issue with low probabilities using `predict_proba(X)`, I think the answer is that according to official doc [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC), *.... Also, it will produce meaningless results on very small datasets.*

The answer residue in understanding what the resulting probablities of SVMs are.
In short, you have 7 classes and 7 points in the 2D plane.
What SVMs are trying to do, is to find a linear separator, between each class and each one the others (one-vs-one approach). Every time only 2 classes are chosen.
What you get is *the votes of the classifiers, after normalization*. See more detailed explanation on multi-class SVMs of *libsvm* in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041753/multi-class-classification-in-libsvm) post or [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/multisvm.pdf) (scikit-learn uses libsvm).

By slightly modifying your code, we see that indeed the right class is chosen:

```
from sklearn import svm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


X = [[0, 0], [10, 10],[20,30],[30,30],[40, 30], [80,60], [80,50]]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
clf = svm.SVC() 
clf.fit(X, y)

x_pred = [[10,10]]
p = np.array(clf.decision_function(x_pred)) # decision is a voting function
prob = np.exp(p)/np.sum(np.exp(p),axis=1, keepdims=True) # softmax after the voting
classes = clf.predict(x_pred)

_ = [print('Sample={}, Prediction={},\n Votes={} \nP={}, '.format(idx,c,v, s)) for idx, (v,s,c) in enumerate(zip(p,prob,classes))]
```

The corresponding output is

```
Sample=0, Prediction=0,
Votes=[ 6.5         4.91666667  3.91666667  2.91666667  1.91666667  0.91666667 -0.08333333] 
P=[ 0.75531071  0.15505748  0.05704246  0.02098475  0.00771986  0.00283998  0.00104477], 
Sample=1, Prediction=1,
Votes=[ 4.91666667  6.5         3.91666667  2.91666667  1.91666667  0.91666667 -0.08333333] 
P=[ 0.15505748  0.75531071  0.05704246  0.02098475  0.00771986  0.00283998  0.00104477], 
Sample=2, Prediction=2,
Votes=[ 1.91666667  2.91666667  6.5         4.91666667  3.91666667  0.91666667 -0.08333333] 
P=[ 0.00771986  0.02098475  0.75531071  0.15505748  0.05704246  0.00283998  0.00104477], 
Sample=3, Prediction=3,
Votes=[ 1.91666667  2.91666667  4.91666667  6.5         3.91666667  0.91666667 -0.08333333] 
P=[ 0.00771986  0.02098475  0.15505748  0.75531071  0.05704246  0.00283998  0.00104477], 
Sample=4, Prediction=4,
Votes=[ 1.91666667  2.91666667  3.91666667  4.91666667  6.5         0.91666667 -0.08333333] 
P=[ 0.00771986  0.02098475  0.05704246  0.15505748  0.75531071  0.00283998  0.00104477], 
Sample=5, Prediction=5,
Votes=[ 3.91666667  2.91666667  1.91666667  0.91666667 -0.08333333  6.5  4.91666667] 
P=[ 0.05704246  0.02098475  0.00771986  0.00283998  0.00104477  0.75531071  0.15505748], 
Sample=6, Prediction=6,
Votes=[ 3.91666667  2.91666667  1.91666667  0.91666667 -0.08333333  4.91666667  6.5       ] 
P=[ 0.05704246  0.02098475  0.00771986  0.00283998  0.00104477  0.15505748  0.75531071],
```

And you can also see decision zones:

```
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

XX, YY = np.mgrid[0:100:200j, 0:100:200j]
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()])

Z = Z.reshape(XX.shape)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))
plt.pcolormesh(XX, YY, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

for idx in range(7):
    ax.scatter(X[idx,0],X[idx,1], color='k')
```

[image]

Comment: I think his major problem is to understand why the probability for the correct class is the smallest out of all. This question is not answered here

Comment: @PKlumpp Thanks, added note on the probablities.

Comment: @mr_mo  What tool /IDE did you use to obtain the plot..? I tried to run the code on Ubuntu terminal... it gave me the prediction but not the graph

Comment: I used `matplotlib.pyplot`. The example is self-contained, this is the code.

Comment: @VidyaMarathe I used it within Jupyter, just add `plt.show()` to see the graph.

Comment: I don't think that this answer is correct. What you refer to as probabilities are not really probabilities. In the [documentation of decision_function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function), [this post is mentioned](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14881/55820) where it is explained why. Similarly, in page 4 of [this document](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/22569/1/tr56-04.pdf) it's also said that the mapping from decision functions to probabilities via softmax "is not very well founded".

Comment: In `SVC()`, the default value of `decision_function_shape` is `’ovr’`, which means it returns a one-vs-rest (‘ovr’) decision function of shape (n_samples, n_classes) as all other classifiers. In this demo, the label space is [0, 1, 2, 3], so `n_classes = 4`. So why P contains 7 results ? Here is my results from `sklearn=0.24.1`: ```Sample=0, Prediction=0,
 Votes=[ 3.16124317  3.19468064  0.87106327  3.17454938 -0.24583347] 
P=[0.31428908 0.32497579 0.03182122 0.31849903 0.01041489], ``` Thanks

Comment: @GuokLiu Actually there are 5 classes. Regarding the P values, it is the number of samples and the "probability" for each one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply @mr_mo. Yes. The label space is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] and `n_classes = 5`. I suppose that replace `x_pred = [[10,10]]` with `x_pred = X` might be clear. It will match the outputs as shown : )

Answer (score 8):

You should disable `probability` and use `decision_function` instead, because there is no guarantee that `predict_proba` and `predict` return the same result. 
You can read more about it, here in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities).

```
clf.predict([[10, 10]]) // returns 1 as expected 

prop = clf.decision_function([[10, 10]]) // returns [[ 4.91666667  6.5         3.91666667  2.91666667  1.91666667  0.91666667
      -0.08333333]]
prediction = np.argmax(prop) // returns 1
```

Comment: your answer does not has fancy plots, but for me is the most useful one, I would only add that you can apply a softmax to the output of the decision_function to convert it to probabilities that is what the user requested add the beggining

Comment: @Kailegh thanks for your feedback. I would appreciate an upvote.

Comment: upps, sorry, there you have it ! =D

Answer (score 2):

You can [read in the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities) that...

> The SVC method decision_function gives per-class scores for each sample (or a single score per sample in the binary case). When the constructor option probability is set to True, class membership probability estimates (from the methods predict_proba and predict_log_proba) are enabled. In the binary case, the **probabilities are calibrated using Platt scaling**: logistic regression on the SVM’s scores, fit by an additional cross-validation on the training data. In the multiclass case, this is extended as per Wu et al. (2004).
>
> Needless to say, **the cross-validation involved in Platt scaling is an expensive operation for large datasets**. **In addition, the probability estimates may be inconsistent with the scores**, in the sense that the “argmax” of the scores may not be the argmax of the probabilities. (E.g., in binary classification, **a sample may be labeled by predict as belonging to a class that has probability <½ according to predict_proba**.) **Platt’s method is also known to have theoretical issues.** If confidence scores are required, but these do not have to be probabilities, then **it is advisable to set probability=False and use decision_function instead of predict_proba.**

There are also lots of confusion about this function amongst Stack Overflow users, as you can see in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017882/scikit-learn-predict-proba-gives-wrong-answers), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111408/how-does-sklearn-svm-svcs-function-predict-proba-work-internally).